# how to replace null value to " " from multi dimensional array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, api, multidimensional-array, woocommerce

I am developing API from Woocommerce for mobile apps. I have integrated woocommerce plugin for APIs and I am getting all the values of woocommerce products and cart but I am facing one issue with null values. If there is null into the output, I need to replace it with " " so app won't get crashed

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

```
NOTE: Please remember that I have multi dimensional array not single dimension
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check the values before using it, something like this would help:

```
  if (a[0][1][3] != null) :
       #do something

  or

  if (a[0][1][3] == null):
       a[0][1][3] = " "
```

you could also create a method and pass the multi dimen array and process it and change null values (if found) from null to ""